# Admob Interstitial exception

Tags: ios, nullpointerexception, admob

I have 2 apps with Admob Interstitials. 
Admob Interstitial stopped to work in 1 app. 
I get exception calling loadRequest method.

**Exception: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key**

```
    interestial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interestial.adUnitID = PUBID;
    //interestial.delegate = interestialDelegate;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [interestial loadRequest:request];
```

I made many many I spent day morfing code. Also I have same working code in another app.
May be it is something in project like missing framework or else

I tried Admob 6.3.0, 6.2.1, 6.1.5

Major change to my Admob code was upgrade to 6.3.0 but second app was also upgraded.

I am logging PUBID. It is not nil.

I do not pass NSDictionary to Admob my self.
The difference between apps is that it works in app with ARC and fails in non ARC app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common problem is `-ObjC` flag in `Other Linker Flags`